# How can I fix “React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency. Either include it or remove the dependency array” problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use useEffect, but when I add getGroup method, I get warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getGroups'.
> Either include it or remove the dependency array"

My code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getGroups();
  setContent(contentGroup);
}, [contentGroup]);


const [content, setContent] = useState([]);
const [groups, setGroups] = useState({});

const getGroups= () => {

   let newGroups = groups;

   contentGroup.forEach(content=>{
     newGroups = {...newGroups , [content.id]: content.title};
   })

   setGroups(newGroups);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `getGroups` does not get re-assigned, or you don't mind the `useEffect` running again if it does, then it should be safe to include it in the dependency array, like the message is eluding to:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getGroups();
  setContent(contentGroup);
}, [contentGroup, getGroups]);
```